# Getting trimmed video file size from UIImagePickerController

Tags: xcode, set, uiimagepickercontroller, trim, alasset

After selecting a video using `UIImagePickerController` I can get the video's file size from its 
`[defaultRepresentation size]`.
However, if I enable the picker's trimming option, `[defaultRepresentation size]` returns the same file size as the original untrimmed video.

Does anyone have a method for retrieving the trimmed video's file size?

Much appreciated...

Yes, I should have included some code. Me bad.

What I'm trying to achieve is have the user choose and trim an existing video, then upload the trimmed version.  I would like to have the trimmed version's file size in order to populate the progress bar during the upload.  I would also like the trimmed version's duration.

The calling method is:

```
-(IBAction)selectVideoPressed:(id)sender
{

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])

{

    UIImagePickerController *videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [videoPicker setDelegate: self];
    [videoPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [videoPicker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil]];
    [videoPicker setVideoQuality:vvi.videoQuality];
    [videoPicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    [videoPicker setModalTransitionStyle:gTransitionStyle];

    [self presentViewController:videoPicker animated:YES completion:Nil];

}

}
```

The delegate method which fires after the user has trimmed and pressed **Choose** is:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[vvi setRawSourceVideoFileURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
[vvi setSourceVideoURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];

ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *myAsset)

{

    // Video metrics info.

    [vvi setVideoDuration:[myAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDuration]];
    [vvi setVideoOrientation:[myAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyOrientation]];
    NSDate *videoDate = [myAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
    [vvi setVideoDateString:[videoDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:gShortDateFormat];
    [vvi setShortVideoDateString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:videoDate]];

    ALAssetRepresentation *myAssetRepresentation = [myAsset defaultRepresentation];
    [vvi setVideoAssetSize:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[myAssetRepresentation size]]];

    NSLog(@"Duration:%@", vvi.videoDuration);
    NSLog(@"Size:%@", vvi.videoAssetSize);

};

 ....
```

`vvi` is just my own custom class.
The two NSLog's return the duration and size of the original untrimmed video.  The video pointed to with `[vvi setRawSourceVideoFileURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];` does return the properly trimmed video.

Thanks and much!

Comment: snippet of code u tried for achieving this is required.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder yes, I guess code would help...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should take care finding the file size of a selected image or video returned from the UIImagePickerController

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        //Error Container
        NSError *attributesError;
        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[videoUrl path] error:&attributesError];
        NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
        long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
}
```

Comment: This has been asked else where but this is the most complete answer!

Comment: can we have a swift 3 version for this plz